# How to make real dynamic footer?

Tags: css

Over the years I've tried lot of different techniques, but I still can't find a way, where I could create a footer, that is dynamically changes height, depending on the content and if the site have less content, the footer goes down to the bottom of the page.

I've tried to play with the ::after pseudo element:

```
footer::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background: red; //just test
    width: 100%;
    height: 99px;
}
```

And I found a way, where you can do this to look nice, but you need to set the height of the footer. But if you want a real responsive UI, you can not set the height of the footer :)

I hope anyone knows the secret, how to create a dynamic footer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you want is sticky footer with fluid height.

In older browsers you'll need some JavaScript.

In modern browser you can use css table display types:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body {
             height: 100%;
             margin: 0pt;
        }
        .Frame {
             display: table;
             height: 100%;
             width: 100%;
        }
        .Row {
             display: table-row;
             height: 1px;
        }
        .Row.Expand {
             height: auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body class="Frame">
    <header class="Row"><h1>Catchy header</h1></header>
    <section class="Row Expand"><h2>Awesome content</h2></section>
    <footer class="Row"><h3>Sticky footer</h3></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

I took this example from:

http://pixelsvsbytes.com/blog/2011/09/sticky-css-footers-the-flexible-way/

EDIT: Now I see you want to expand the footer, not the content. I'm leaving the original for bypassers with sticky footer question as it is more common version.

Try this version instead:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body {
             height: 100%;
             margin: 0pt;
        }
        .Frame {
             display: table;
             height: 100%;
             width: 100%;
        }
        .Row {
             display: table-row;
             height: 1px;
        }
        .Row.Expand {
             height: auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body class="Frame">
    <header class="Row"><h1>Catchy header</h1></header>

    <!-- these two line differ from the previous example -->
    <section class="Row"><h2>Awesome content</h2></section> 
    <footer class="Row Expand"><h3>Sticky footer</h3></footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this way, but the only thing changed, is the whole content went down to the bottom. So the footer is in the bottom, but I've got a huge empty space in the top of the page. :\ I'm trying this way a bit more...

Comment: The second is better, but it only work, when I disable and re-enable one of the `display` rules in the Developer Tools (Chrome). Maybe that's a bug in Chrome, because this solution is really near. And one more thing, the footers top border disappears... Probably this is because of the display mode and I can put it back somehow else, but it's weird anyways :)

Comment: It's probably due to something else happening on your page since it works if you take this code only. Could you provide a jsfiddle with this bug?

Comment: I played a little with it and you are right. It was something else... Btw. Great code, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This can easily [be done](http://jsfiddle.net/LDeGa/3/) with CSS2.1 (but not in IE7-). The main trick is the following:

```
.container {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100% /* mimics `display: block` */
}
.footer {
    display: table-footer-group;
}
/* to add padding use the below or wrapper/inner wrapping element combo. */
.footer:before, .footer:after {
    padding: 1em;
    content: '';
}
```

In modern browsers, it can also be done with FlexBox, which is probably more appropriate theoretically, but less supported yet.

Comment: Simply elegant, `height: 1px` is optional?

Comment: @DanielSokolowski, in modern browsers it seems so. But some years ago some browsers tended to size footer and content areas proportionally to the content without it.

Answer (score -2):

It is sticky footer, please try this:

#### HTML

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="header">Header Section</div>
   <div id="page" class="clearfix">
      <div id="left">Left Sidebar</div>
      <div id="content">Main content</div>
      <div id="right">Right sidebar</div>
   </div>
   <div id="footer">Footer Section</div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
/*sticky footer style*/
html,body {
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
  height: 100%;
}
#container {
  min-height:100%;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 100%; /*for ie6*/
  position: relative;
}
#header {
  background: #ff0;
  padding: 10px;
}
#page {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-bottom: 60px;/* equal to the footer's height*/
}

#footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;/*The footer' height*/
  background: #6cf;
  clear:both;
}
/*=======主体内容部分=======*/
#left {
  width: 220px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
  background: lime;
}
#content {
  background: orange;
  float: left;
  width: 480px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
#right{
  background: green;
  float: right;
  width: 220px;
}
```

Pleas view the [demo](http://codepen.io/airen/pen/JLDwk). Other methods, you can click [here](http://www.w3cplus.com/css/css-sticky-foot-at-bottom-of-the-page).

And you can use the CSS3 flexbox Module, Like this:

#### HTML

```
  <header class="Row"><h1>Catchy header</h1></header>
  <section class="Row Expand"><h2>Awesome content</h2></section>
  <footer class="Row"><h3>Sticky footer</h3></footer>
```

#### CSS

```
header,section,footer {
  display: block;
}
html,body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  width: 100%;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;

  -moz-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -moz-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}
section {
  -moz-box-flex:1;
  -webkit-box-flex:1;
  -ms-flex:1;
  -webkit-flex:1;
  flex:1;

  background: hsla(250,20%,30%,0.9);
}
header {
  background: orange;
}
footer {
  background: green;
}
```

Please view the [demo](http://codepen.io/airen/pen/kLoHE). About the [css3 flexbox module](http://www.w3cplus.com/css3/designing-css-layout-with-flexbox.html).

Comment: It's wrong solution since it defines footer height which must be fluid. The second one in your answer is better but the footer must be flex, not the content.

Comment: the footer is flex, it is not fix height.

Comment: No it isn't. You'll have to do footer { flex:1; } for it to be flexible. This is NOT the common sticky footer.